# How can I make set up a shading scheme in blender that creates a color map when rendered?

Tags: animation

I am using robotic painting to render an animation and I am limited to a set of 10 colors which I can paint with.

I want to create a setup in blender in which I designate those 10 colors as materials and apply them to objects/characters. The final image should consist of only those colors so that the parser can sense the rgb values and create robot code respectively.

Essentially, I don't want any lighting, antialiasing, or variation from these 10 colors in the cycles render result.

I cannot figure out how to keep lighting from affecting the final color values which are flat shading objects.

How can I do this in blender?

Comment: Just a check, why are you using Cycles? (You'll still be able to do it, by extracting color passes, but....) it seems a waste if all you want to see is flat color?

Answer (score 1):

if you want a flat color in Cycles you have to use the emission shader.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use compositing:

- create your scene with your objects and use 10 different materials (it doesn't matter their color for now) and enable **Material passes**

[image]

- give to each material a different ID index

[image]

- in the compositor use ID masks like in the picture to replace the objects with your solid flat colors (you need to put the colors you want in the **Alpha Over** nodes)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Or try this- lose anything resembling a shader and just input your colour directly into the 'surface' output in the nodes, and drop your render samples to 1 (Eevee or cycles) and off you go...
[image]

Looks fairly flat & not anti-aliased to me...